# Precision long double worse than double

Tags: c++, double-precision, long-double

When I use `long double` I get worse precision than using `double`.
`3.14159265358979323846264L` is this good to write `long double const` in source code or I should add something other than `L`?

EDIT
I solved the problem. I change algorithm to be more precisely.

Comment: What platform / architecture / compiler? What did you actually observe?

Comment: You're going to need to explain yourself more. Show us some code using double, some code using long double, the results from each, and why you think the results are wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your are not getting a worse precision.

What is happening is that when you print the number out the stream library is truncating the displayed value. Use std::setprecision to get a specific precision.

```
double        x = 1.0/3;
long double   y = 1.0/6;

// Prints out the precision
std::cout << "Limit: " << std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 << "\n";
std::cout << "Limit: " << std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10 << "\n";

// prints the numbers with max precision.
std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10) << x << "\n";
std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10) << y << "\n";
```